# Keeping current working cell in the middle of the page - jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

How can I keep my current input cell always in the middle of the page? In jupyter notebook, after some time, your working cell comes to the end of the page, and it is irritating to look at the bottom and work.

How can I keep the working cell always in the middle or at the top of the page?